# Reducing the number of mosaic elements using gdal_merge

Tags: qgis, gdal, mosaic, gdal-merge

I have 4 thousand mosaic elements. So i would like to reduce their count. (for example to 1 thousand, merge every 4 elements)
How can i do this? gdal_merge give me one big raster

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand what is your aim, but giving a short list of files that you want to merge for gdal_merge feels like a simple option. However, building a virtual raster with gdalbuildvrt is often a good alternative.

Comment: GDALBuildVRT https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html will take an input file list *-input_file_list my_list.txt*, if you can export the file names (from windows dir *.tif /b /s > my_list.txt) then break up the list by file names by file names you can create small clusters; without knowing your source data, how it's named and where it's stored I can't be of much help. You could build a VRT for all the data and deal with a single file but refresh rates on very large VRT files is abominable and building overviews is very slow.